# My cli engine(npm package) cant find path to read file when install on another folder

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I am building an app that auto completes some type of file. When i run node index.js in the program folder i get the correct i results. 
Although i want to make it an npm package that can work as a cli engine. For example i want to write the command generate and the code to produce the results.

In order to auto complete the file i have to read some data that i have stored in a .csv file that comes along with my program.

When i try to run generate command under another folder it can read that file.

I am very new to cli and i don't understand yet quite well how thing work.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is the code of my cli conversion.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const program = require("commander");
const {
  predict
} = require("./classifier");

program.version("1.0.0").description("ESLint Rules Generator");

program
  .command("generate")
  .description("Generate ESLint Rules")
  .action(() => {
    predict();
  });

program.parse(process.argv);
```

Here is the problematic line:

```
let str = fs.readFileSync("data_files/rules.csv", "utf-8");
```

This is the error i get: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'data_files/rules.csv'

Comment: Probably an issue due to `cwd` and you using a relative path that implicitly uses it. Try using `path.join(__dirname, 'data_files/rules.csv')` (and `const path = require('path')` beforehand, obviously).

Comment: Thank you. Tried it and it seems to work properly!